# sharepoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have created a custom list. I have a field called manager Email. Whenever a list items gets added to this field manager should get an email. This workflow should be automatic.

Any directions please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Whenever a list items gets added" sounds like an [Event Receiver](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2006-7-Sharepoint_2007__List_Events_Practical_Example__Creating_a_rigged_survey.aspx) to me rather than a workflow:

```
public class MyEventReceiver : SPItemEventReceiver 
{
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
            SPUtility.SendEmail(web, true, true, item["ManagerEmail"].ToString(), "Subject", "Body");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

You attach this code to a list through a Feature. If you have created a custom list template, you can use the [Receivers Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460929%28v=office.12%29.aspx). But if the custom list was created through the UI, you will need to use a Feature Receiver:

```
public class MyFeatureReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver {

    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties) {
        using (SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb)
        {
            Type type = typeof(MyEventReceiver);
            SPList list = web.Lists["My Custom List"];
            list.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdded, type.Assembly.FullName, type.FullName);
            list.Update();
        }
    }

    public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties) {
    }
    public override void FeatureInstalled(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties) {
    }
    public override void FeatureUninstalling(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties) {
    }
}
```

For more information:

- [How to: Create an Event Handler Feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453149%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Feature Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469501%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: the items are added from the user interface which I have created a form in designer with the validation. So I am not sure where do I write this peice of code?

Comment: You attach the Event Receiver to the list with a Feature. See my edit for more information.